# Making new column with multiple elements after group_by

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a new column as described below. the d's actually correspond to dates and V2 are events on the given dates. I need to collect the events for the given date. V3 is a single column whose row entries are a concatenation. Thanks in advance. My attempt does not work.

```
 df =   V1    V2 
        d1    U
        d2    M
        d1    T
        d1    Q
        d2    P
```

desired resulting df

```
  df.1 = V1      V3
         d1      U,T,Q
         d2      M,P


 df.1 <- df %>% group_by(., V1) %>%
         mutate(., V3 = c(distinct(., V2))) %>%
         as.data.frame
```

The above code results in the following error; ignore the 15 and 1s--they're specific to my actual code

```
Error: incompatible size (15), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not allow a vector as an element in data frame. So instead of using c(), you can use paste to concatenate elements as a single string.

`df.1 <- df %>% group_by(V1) %>% mutate(V3 = paste(unique(V2), collapse = ",")) %>% select(V1, V3) %>% unique() %>% as.data.frame()`

Comment: The input of the unique() function here is the input of the %>% before it. So it is equivalent to unique(.), and the . here can be left out, the same way that `df %>% group_by(., V1)` can be written as `df %>% group_by(V1)` and df will be the default first argument of the group_by function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate like this:

```
df.1 <- aggregate(V2~V1,paste,collapse=",",data=df)

#  V1    V2
# 1 d1 U,T,Q
# 2 d2   M,P
```

Answer (score 0):

still with `dplyr`, you can try:

```
df %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarize(V3 = paste(unique(V2), collapse=", "))
```